# Is every vector field a gradient vector field with respect to a pseudo metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

**Edit:** According to the comment of Prof. Bryant we revise the question as follows:

Assume that $X$ is a smooth vector field on an open  manifold $M$, for exmple $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a non degenerate pseudo Riemannian metric on $M$ such that $X$ is a gradient vector field?
If not what type of obstructions would appear?

Comment: No.  Let $X$ be a vector field on the $2$-sphere that has a closed orbit.  It cannot be the gradient vector field of any non-degenerate metric on the $2$-sphere.  Closed integral curves are clearly an obstruction, and there are many such kinds of of obstructions of a dynamial nature, probably too many to classify.

Comment: @RobertBryant Is not possible that $\nabla f. \nabla f=0$ along closed orbit?

Comment: No.  Any non-degenerate pseudo-Riemannian metric on $S^2$ has to be either positive or negative definite because the tangent bundle of $S^2$ cannot be split into the sum of two line bundles.  The same argument applies to any surface with nonzero Euler characteristic and a vector field with a closed orbit.

Comment: @RobertBryant  for example $\nabla xy= y\partial _x -x\partial_y$ with $dx^2- dy^2$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Yes thank you very much. So I revise the question for an open manifold for example for the plane.